# How to bring a integer data from database to a JTextField in swing user interface

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I tried making a swing user interface  component which have two TextField one take the name of product for which it returns the price of product present in database.
There are some mistakes in code please refer some solution.
code is as follow:

```
class Swingui implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame jf=new JFrame("PRODUCT DETAILS");
    JLabel jl1=new JLabel("Product:");
    JTextField jtf1=new JTextField();
    JTextField jtf2=new JTextField();
    JLabel jl2=new JLabel("Price:");
    JButton jb=new JButton("enter");
    Swingui()
    {
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jl1.setBounds(50,70,100,30);
        jf.add(jl1);
        jtf1.setBounds(50,100,100,30);
        jf.add(jtf1);
        jl2.setBounds(50,150,100,30);
        jf.add(jl2);
        jb.setBounds(50,250,100,30);
        jf.add(jb);
        jtf2.setBounds(50,200,100,30);
        jf.add(jtf2);
        jb.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        new Swingui();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/product";
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
            /*error*/Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            String qry="select price from price where good='"+jtf1.getText().toString()+"'";
            /*error*/ResultSet resultSet= stmt.executeQuery(qry);
            int price = resultSet.getInt("price");
            JLabel jl3=new JLabel();
            String str;
            str=String.valueOf(price);
            jl3.setText(str);
            jl3.setBounds(50,300,100,50);
            jf.add(jl3);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MySQL database details are:

```
         database: product
         table : price
         columns are 
         good      price
         ==============
         gold10gm   35000
         dollar       78
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome? what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the localhost port number in the URL. The resultSet maintains a cursor to the current row of data fetched. And initially, the cursor will be pointing before the current row and so you cannot directly fetch the results from the result set. Try iterating it before accessing the values.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next())
    rs.getInt("price");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String qry="select * from price where good= ? ";
   PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(qry);
   stmt.SetString(jtf1.getText().toString);
   stmt.execute();
   
   ResultSet resultSet= stmt.getResultSet();
   while (resultSet.next()) {
     int price = resultSet.getInt("price");
   }

   JLabel jl3=new JLabel();
   String str;
   str=Integer.toString(price);
   jl3.setText(str);
   stmt.close(); // close the prepare statement if you don't need it further
```

Comment: Instead of String.ValueOf(price) try Integer.toString(price)

Comment: You can try to use a preparedStatement instead of an sql statement so as to insert the value of your string later